# Rails reserved words and convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions, reserved-words

After having spent a lot of time researching Rails reserved words and implementing, I still have a few questions regarding use.

In my example here, I'll consider the reserved word 'time'. 
Let's say I want to create a class 'Timepiece'. Is it not recommended to use 'timepiece' because the name begins with 'time'? Would it be recommended to use 'time_piece' or to avoid inserting the reserved word at all? My question here is also about use of the exact reserved word within the class like that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `time` a reserved word?

How does `time_piece` not use a reserved word like `timepiece` does?

In any case, name your classes what they should be named: there's no reason, technical, cultural, semantic, or otherwise, not to use a reserved word *inside* a class or variable name, even if `Time` was the same as `time` (it isn't) and `time` was reserved (AFAIK it isn't).

Let's instead say you meant `Time`, which isn't a reserved word, but *is* an existing class. If you name something `Time` you're re-opening the class. If you name something with `Time` *in* it it's entirely unrelated to `Time` itself, and whether or not you *should* use it as part of the name has more to do with semantics than anything else: again, no reason *not* to.

Comment: Appreciate it, Dave. Thanks for the response and explanation. I'll ponder. Don't have enough cred points to vote, but I checked it.